# how to take particular value from array in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to get only value of "_workAgent" where _activityStatus"=="I",.

Please review my code I am getting value like below.

["501"]

0: "501"

length: 1

while I have to just take 501 value in one variable

```
     "workAgent_ID": [
              {
                "_activityName": "FXL_ACT1",
                "_activityStatus": "I",
                "_userName": "tecnotree",
                "_maxHoldTime": "60",
                "_workAgent": "501"
              },
              {
                "_activityName": "FXL_ACT2",
                "_activityStatus": "N",
                "_userName": null,
                "_maxHoldTime": "120",
                "_workAgent": "510"
              }

   const currentStepPosition = workAgent_ID.filter((item) => {
        return item._activityStatus === "I"
          });
       const workAgentID = currentStepPosition.map(currentStepPosition => {
        return currentStepPosition._workAgent;
           });
```

Comment: could you please update my answer ..oneway is workAgentID[0] buti dont want to this

Answer (score 0):

`map` return a new collection of array.
In your case, I think you don't need to map your `currentStepPosition`.
Just do the following code:

```
const currentStepPosition = workAgent_ID.filter((item) => {
        return item._activityStatus === "I"
          })[0];

const workAgentID  = currentStepPosition._workAgent
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple approach you can take, This logic will not fail if the object is not found. So It will work for both scenarios.

```js
var values =    { "workAgent_ID": [
              {
                "_activityName": "FXL_ACT1",
                "_activityStatus": "I",
                "_userName": "tecnotree",
                "_maxHoldTime": "60",
                "_workAgent": "501"
              },
              {
                "_activityName": "FXL_ACT2",
                "_activityStatus": "N",
                "_userName": null,
                "_maxHoldTime": "120",
                "_workAgent": "510"
              }]}


const index = values.workAgent_ID.findIndex(item => item._activityStatus === "I")
if(index > -1){
  console.log("Result object", values.workAgent_ID[index])
}
```